Cloudflare page rule 301 redirect
I have a page rule in cloudflare to redirect example.com to www.example.com  with 301 redirect
Curl correctly shows 301 redirect but browser is showing 307 redirect.  How can I make the browser also see 301 redirect ?

How did you set up the rule?  The opposite sometimes happens (some providers change 307 to 301 if it happens often enough), but not that direction.
